# Push notification not opening built-in External Link

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have used exact same method to open a content intent from notification but instead it's opening my app itself on FCM push notification.

My code:

```
public class ddkeysFirebaseMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    String deviceToken = s;
    saveString("deviceToken", deviceToken);
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Intent downloadLink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    downloadLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));

    PendingIntent opendwdlink = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, downloadLink, 0);

    String title = Objects.requireNonNull(remoteMessage.getNotification()).getTitle();
    String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

    cloudNotificationManager.getDkInstance(getApplicationContext())
            .cloudNotification(title, body, opendwdlink);
}

}
```

And my notification builder is here, Please correct me if anything wrong here

```
public class cloudNotificationManager {

private static cloudNotificationManager dkInstance;
private final Context cloudcontext;

private cloudNotificationManager(Context context) {
    cloudcontext = context;
}

public static synchronized cloudNotificationManager getDkInstance(Context context) {
    if (dkInstance == null) {
        dkInstance = new cloudNotificationManager(context);
    }
    return dkInstance;
}

public void cloudNotification(String title, String body, PendingIntent dwdlink) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder cBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(cloudcontext, ddKeys_init.CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    if (dwdlink != null) {
        cBuilder.setContentIntent(dwdlink);
    }


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) cloudcontext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (notificationManager != null) {
        notificationManager.notify(111, cBuilder.build());
    }
}


}
```

I have followed exact way shown in other posts but not working.

I FOUND MY PROBLEM.

Problem is with something else. The provided link opens if am within the my APP (app opened, any activity) but it opens the APP if I didn't opened my app  (Like am in another app or in home screen).

I still don't know how to overcome this

Answer (score 0):

Before you set ACTION in intent you have to check the URL is perfect or not. Check below code that how to check that URL is perfect for ACTION or not

```
public Intent getLinkIntent(String url)
{
      Intent intent = null;
      try {
            String patter = "^(http|https|ftp)://.*$";
            if (url.matches(patter)) {
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            }else{
                String newUrl = "https://" + url;
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(newUrl));
            }
      }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return intent;
}
```

Comment: I have found the issue. Let me check if any posts related to my issue there or not. Issue included in last potion of my post

Comment: Also thank you for this answer, I could really use this code in my app :-)